# Gazebo launch file switch between world files

Tags: ros, gazebo, roslaunch, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package built and have successfully tested the tutorial world and spawned several robots. However I want to make my own worlds now, but want to easily switch the world that I am using. So if I want to be able to do something like:

```
roslaunch lawnbot_gazebo lawnbot.launch -gas_station_world
```

to start the gas station world then do:

```
 roslaunch lawnbot_gazebo lawnbot.launch -bot_test_world
```

I am not trying to run multiple worlds at once. I just want to choose the world to start from the terminal instead of modifying the launch file every time I want to change the world.

Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>
<!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find lawnbot_gazebo)/worlds/lawnbot_tutorial_gas_station.world"/>
    <!-- more default parameters can be changed here -->
  </include>
</launch>
```

How do I add arguments that specify which world I am trying to load? Do I have to have multiple launch files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273760/gazebo-launch-file-switch-between-world-files/) by [josiahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/32344/josiahl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the `<arg>` tag to pass arguments to your launch files on the command line: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg

In your case, something simple like this would probably do:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="world" default="lawnbot_tutorial_gas_station"/>
<!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find lawnbot_gazebo)/worlds/$(arg world).world"/>
    <!-- more default parameters can be changed here -->
  </include>
</launch>
```

And then on the command line, you would do:

```
roslaunch lawnbot_gazebo lawnbot.launch world:=bot_test_world
```

Or

```
roslaunch lawnbot_gazebo lawnbot.launch world:=lawnbot_tutorial_gas_station
```

and it would load the desired world file from the lawnbot_gazebo package.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [josiahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/32344/josiahl/) on 2017-10-21**:
Thank you, it works very well!